# RavenDB within ASP.NET MVC with Unity causes ResolutionFailedException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ravendb

I have the following:

- ASP.NET MVC 5
- RavenDB.Client version="3.0.3690"
- Unity version="3.5.1404.0"
- Unity.Mvc latest

Periodically, especially after the ASP.NET application has been idle for some time, upon loading the page I get the following exception:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ResolutionFailedException 
    Exception message: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MyCompany.Web.Controllers.MainController", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor XXXXXXXX.
Exception is: FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d4bfe873e7598c49' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Note that ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp appears to be an **embedded** assembly inside **RavenDB**. I don't reference it anywhere in my code, and it's not in the bin folder.
I never get this error in a console or WPF application, so it must be something with unloading AppDomains and/or recycling ASP.NET AppPools.

Perhaps the code in Unity.Mvc doesn't handle the unloading of embedded assemblies properly. Or perhaps something is missing from the  section of my web.config.

Once I get the error, I hit the F5 (Refresh) button in the browser, and viola, the error goes away and the page loads as expected.

Any idea?

Thanks,
-Alec.